# How do I do real-time conversion of SQL Server data to a JSON format using ASP.NET and Visual Studio?

Tags: json, visual-studio-2013, frontend, real-time-data

My overall goal would be to take data that I get from MS SQL server, and I would like for the data to export, real time, onto a JSON format so that the data can be integrated to the AM Charts Dataloader that would then appear in the front end as a line graph that would constantly keep trending as new information comes into the SQL Server.

I plan on having real-time information being forwarded from MS SQL server to the Front End Web Page. So basically, how would I convert data to JSON, and how would I make it so that the information is updated in real time as the server receives new information?

I'm using Visual Studio to load the SQL Server data and from there I want to integrate the JSON Data to the website. So far I have nothing other than the SQL Server connected to Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: This is far too broad of a question.

Answer (score 0):

A broad question, with many ways to implement. One being the below

Convert data to Json? You can use [JSON.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/)

There are lots of examples shown on the Documentation section. You can construct your object using the library and perform the needed operation.

> "How would I make it so that the information is updated in real time
>   as the server receives new information?"

You can construct a sqlcachedependency.